# Web servlet url pattern

Tags: servlets

How would I express a url like:

`<context>/{id}/email` in the `@WebServlet("...")` syntax?

the default/context is `users`

Comment: something like `@WebServlet("/*/email")` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. It does not appear like dynamic URL patterns are allowed in the `@WebServlet("...")`.

I had to create a URL filter that would parse an incoming URL, extract `{id}` from it and set it as an attribute in the Session, and forward the request to the appropriate Servlet.